# why the json string passed from python flask to js has wrong symbol and can't be parsed

Tags: javascript, json

I used `flask` to create a `json` string and pass it to a `*.js` file to further process.

Below is the string printed by `console.log`.

```
{{&#34;id&#34;:1, &#34;Event&#34;:&#34;Event1&#34;, &#34;sdateTime&#34;:&#34;2023-01-16 15:21:08.133579&#34;, &#34;edateTime&#34;:&#34;2023-01-17 15:21:08.133579&#34;, &#34;position&#34;:&#34;Berth1&#34;},
{&#34;id&#34;:2, &#34;Event&#34;:&#34;Event2&#34;, &#34;sdateTime&#34;:&#34;2023-01-16 15:21:08.133579&#34;, &#34;edateTime&#34;:&#34;2023-01-17 15:21:08.133579&#34;, &#34;position&#34;:&#34;Berth2&#34;},
{&#34;id&#34;:3, &#34;Event&#34;:&#34;Event3&#34;, &#34;sdateTime&#34;:&#34;2023-01-16 15:21:08.133579&#34;, &#34;edateTime&#34;:&#34;2023-01-17 15:21:08.133579&#34;, &#34;position&#34;:&#34;Berth3&#34;},
{&#34;id&#34;:4, &#34;Event&#34;:&#34;Event4&#34;, &#34;sdateTime&#34;:&#34;2023-01-16 15:21:08.133579&#34;, &#34;edateTime&#34;:&#34;2023-01-17 15:21:08.133579&#34;, &#34;position&#34;:&#34;Berth4&#34;},
{&#34;id&#34;:5, &#34;Event&#34;:&#34;Event5&#34;, &#34;sdateTime&#34;:&#34;2023-01-16 15:21:08.133579&#34;, &#34;edateTime&#34;:&#34;2023-01-17 15:21:08.133579&#34;, &#34;position&#34;:&#34;Berth5&#34;},
{&#34;id&#34;:6, &#34;Event&#34;:&#34;Event6&#34;, &#34;sdateTime&#34;:&#34;2023-01-16 15:21:08.133579&#34;, &#34;edateTime&#34;:&#34;2023-01-17 15:21:08.133579&#34;, &#34;position&#34;:&#34;Berth6&#34;},
{&#34;id&#34;:7, &#34;Event&#34;:&#34;Event7&#34;, &#34;sdateTime&#34;:&#34;2023-01-16 15:21:08.133579&#34;, &#34;edateTime&#34;:&#34;2023-01-17 15:21:08.133579&#34;, &#34;position&#34;:&#34;Berth7&#34;},
{&#34;id&#34;:8, &#34;Event&#34;:&#34;Event8&#34;, &#34;sdateTime&#34;:&#34;2023-01-16 15:21:08.133579&#34;, &#34;edateTime&#34;:&#34;2023-01-17 15:21:08.133579&#34;, &#34;position&#34;:&#34;Berth8&#34;}}
```

The original string is like below, which is printed in `app.py` (in `flask`):

```
event_jsonstring = {{"id":1, "Event":"Event1", "sdateTime":"2023-01-16 15:21:08.133579", "edateTime":"2023-01-17 15:21:08.133579", "position":"Berth1"},
{"id":2, "Event":"Event2", "sdateTime":"2023-01-16 15:21:08.133579", "edateTime":"2023-01-17 15:21:08.133579", "position":"Berth2"},
{"id":3, "Event":"Event3", "sdateTime":"2023-01-16 15:21:08.133579", "edateTime":"2023-01-17 15:21:08.133579", "position":"Berth3"},
{"id":4, "Event":"Event4", "sdateTime":"2023-01-16 15:21:08.133579", "edateTime":"2023-01-17 15:21:08.133579", "position":"Berth4"},
{"id":5, "Event":"Event5", "sdateTime":"2023-01-16 15:21:08.133579", "edateTime":"2023-01-17 15:21:08.133579", "position":"Berth5"},
{"id":6, "Event":"Event6", "sdateTime":"2023-01-16 15:21:08.133579", "edateTime":"2023-01-17 15:21:08.133579", "position":"Berth6"},
{"id":7, "Event":"Event7", "sdateTime":"2023-01-16 15:21:08.133579", "edateTime":"2023-01-17 15:21:08.133579", "position":"Berth7"},
{"id":8, "Event":"Event8", "sdateTime":"2023-01-16 15:21:08.133579", "edateTime":"2023-01-17 15:21:08.133579", "position":"Berth8"}}
```

The relevant codes are show as below:

In `app.py` : use flask to do some query and convert the result to a `json` string,
then pass the string to a `html`

```
@app.route("/berth_use")
@login_required
def berth_use():
    event_all = Event.query.all()
    event_jsonstring = event_to_jsonstr(event_all)
    print(event_jsonstring)
    return render_template("berth_use.html", event_data=event_jsonstring)
```

In `berth_use.html` : the `json` string is passed to variable `event_jsonstr`

```
 <script >
    var event_jsonstr = `{{event_data}}`
 </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/try.js"></script>
```

In `try.js` : variable `event_jsonstr` is further to be processed, however the string value contains strange symbol of `&#34`

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(event_jsonstr))
/*The above shows the strange &#34 */

const obj_1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event_jsonstr))

console.log(obj_1[0].id)
/*The above shows message of undefined*/
```

Comment: `&#34;` is the numeric entity for `"`, so it looks like at some point some "HTML escaping" has happened.

Comment: Your JSON string is being subject to HTML entity encoding, which turns the quote characters into those HTML escapes. You'll have to tell the template not to do that. I *think* `{{event_data|safe}}` will do that.